# What is the relation of $\int f dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge ...\wedge dx^n=\int f dx^1...dx^n$

Tags: calculus, analysis, integration, differential-forms

In a book "calculus on manifolds" it is defined that $\int f dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge ...\wedge dx^n=\int f dx^1...dx^n$ but how it is possible the relate the integrand of a multilinear function (n-differential form) with the remann integral. when i am learning remann integration, i considered $dx$ as an infinitestimal distance although the lecturer didn't explain isolately what $dx$ is. I don't quite see the relationship between remann integral and tensors

Comment: I know that there is a connection between what $dx$ means in terms of measure and what $dx$ means in terms of differential forms, which is kept "in secret" for most people. The *infinitesimal distance* used in most calculus books is an approach to the problem which is non-standard in Analysis, though I believe it was broadly used and accepted in the Pre-Riemann calculus.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *definition*. See bottom of pg. 100 of Spivak's book.

If $\omega$ is a $k$-form on $[0,1]^k$, there is a unique $f$ such that $\omega = f dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^k$. Then define
$$
\int_{[0,1]^k} \omega := \int_{[0,1]^k} f
$$
or
$$
\int_{[0,1]^k} f dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^k= \int_{[0,1]^k} f(x^1,\cdots,x^k)dx^1\cdots dx^k
$$